# what is wrong with the if statement in the code below?

Tags: python, function, definition

can someone explain what's wrong with the below code?

```
     def factorial(num):
        if num == 0 or 1:
           return 1
        else:
           result = num * factorial(num-1)
           return result

#print(factorial(30))
#output: 1
```

& on the contrary when the if statement is slightly modified as below. The code seems to do what its meant to do. I would appreciate if someone could comment on why the code below provides desired output while the code above doesn't

```
     def factorial(num):
        if num == 1 or 0:
           return 1
        else:
           result = num * factorial(num-1)
           return result
 #print(factorial(30))
 #265252859812191058636308480000000
```

Comment: `if num == 0 or num == 1`

Comment: This is due to operator precedence. The or operator has a lower precedence than the == test, so the latter is evaluated first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num == 0 or 1` isn't doing what you think it is.

This could instead be `num == 0 or num == 1` or `num in [0,1]`.

Comment: Of course it's valid syntax, it just doesn't do what they expect

Comment: Ah, you're right, poor wording. Updated.

Comment: That's useful feedback, thanks :)

Comment: @samwalton what you said is what I already know. I'm not used to wording my questions in a way search would suggest to me what I'm looking for. It's particularly hard when one is short on time and has a ton to do.